# Variable type with objects having a different structure cause error Property 'propertyname' does not exist

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this interface that i use as type for a variable inside a component

```
export interface IToolbarConfig 
{
    items:
    [
        {
            type?:string,
            label?:string,
            handler?:Function
        } ?,
        {
            type?:string,
            label?:string,
        } ?
    ] 
}
```

Into toolbar.component.ts:

```
@Input() config!: IToolbarConfig;
```

So, i try to cycle the items array into the toolbar.component.html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of config?.items">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item?.type == 'button'">
        <button (click)="item?.handler()">{{ item?.label }}</button> 
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Due the fact that property "*handler*" exists only when *type="button"*, compiler give me error

**Property 'handler' does not exist on type '{ type?: string | undefined; label?: string | undefined; handler?: Function |
undefined; } | { type?: string | undefined; label?: string | undefined; }'.**

I managed to solve modifing interface so

```
export interface IToolbarConfig 
{
    items:
    [
        {
            type?:string,
            label?:string,
            handler?:Function
        } ?,
        {
            type?:string,
            label?:string,
        } ?
    ] | any   <------added this
}
```

but i don't think this is the best practice. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Change your interface in:

```
// since handler can be undefined your interface was duplicating objects in the array
export interface IToolbarConfig {
  items: Array<{
    type?: string
    label?: string
    handler?: Function
  } | undefined>
}
```

And then, [as said by Rabu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72745179/17264570) call the method with the optional chaining:

```
<button (click)="item?.handler?.()">{{ item?.label }}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`handler` could be `undefined` so you need to add a check for it. You can use optional chaining on the function also.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of config?.items">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item?.type == 'button'">
        <button (click)="item?.handler?.()">{{ item?.label }}</button> 
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: done, but the error still occurs

Answer (score 0):

why not type `items` as

```
{ 
  type?:string,
  label?: string,
  handler?:Function,
}[]
```

The fact that your type uses `?` on handler means that it doesn't need to be defined. That means even if you type is not button and you don't have any handler to define, you can leave it undefined, typescript won't complain

This declaration is now valid

```
let item: items = [{
  type: 'myType',
  label: 'myLabel',
}]
```